# save image to album with custom image name swift

Tags: save, uiimage, swift5

Hello I am saving image to my custom album it saved successfully but random image. I want to save it with custom name. How can I save image with its custom name.

here is code for saving image to custom folder.

```
func save(image: UIImage, completion: @escaping (Result<Bool, Error>) -> ()) {
        self.checkAuthorizationWithHandler { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let success):
                if success, self.assetCollection != nil {
                    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                        let assetChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
                        
                        let assetPlaceHolder = assetChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
                        if let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: self.assetCollection) {
                            let enumeration: NSArray = [assetPlaceHolder!]
                            albumChangeRequest.addAssets(enumeration)
                        }
                    }, completionHandler: { (success, error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("Error writing to image library: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            completion(.failure(error))
                            return
                        }
                        completion(.success(success))
                    })
                }
            case .failure(let err):
                completion(.failure(err))
            }
        }
    }
```